# Getting JSON in to Underscore Template in Backbone

Tags: json, backbone.js, underscore.js

Just getting started with Backbone and still making sense of the ins and outs.

I'm trying to simply display some JSON using Underscore and Backbone. I'm able to make it to work just using Underscore and $.getJSON, but when I try to wire it up with Backbone I get a variety of errors depending upon what I try.

I've also been able to get Backbone to work by hardcoding values in to the model, but I'm running in to a wall when I try to bring it all together. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my Underscore template:

```
<script type="text/html" id='trailTemplate'>

    <% _.each(trails,function(trail){ %>

        <%= trail.trailname %><br />

    <% }); %>

</script>
```

And here is my Backbone code:

```
var Trail = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "trails.json"
});

var trail = new Trail({});

var TrailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page',

    template: _.template($("#trailTemplate").html(), {trails:trail.fetch()}),

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var trailView = new TrailView({
    model: trail
});

trailView.render();
```

And in case you need it, here is trails.json

```
[
        {
            "trailhead": "Bear Lake",
            "trailname": "Bear Lake",
            "distance": ".5",
            "gain": "20",
            "level": "easy"
        },

        {
            "trailhead": "Bear Lake",
            "trailname": "Nymph Lake",
            "distance": ".5",
            "gain": "225",
            "level": "fairly easy"
        }
]
```

Comment: You probably want a collection for that JSON, not a single model. And you want `template: _.template($("#trailTemplate").html())`,  `this.$el.html(this.template({ trails: this.collection.toJSON() })`, and `new TrailView({ collection: trails })`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `trails.json` file contains an array with 2 objects, which both represent a single 'Trail'. So you should have a collection 'Trails' instead of a single model

```
var Trails = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/trails.json'
});

var trails = new Trails();
```

The underscore [template function](http://underscorejs.org/#template) can be used in 2 ways:

1. **_.template(templateString)** - compiles the templateString into function that can be evaluated when necessary
2. **_.template(templateString, data)** - compiles and immediately evaluates the template with the given data

Now the way you are using is number 2 (the way you declare the template) combined with number 1 (how you use it inside render). Let's examine the template declaration:

```
template: _.template($("#trailTemplate").html(), {trails:trail.fetch()})
```

This is all good up until the point you try to give it the `data` -attribute. First of all **you don't need to give the data at this point**, you just want to create the template function that can be evaluated when the View renders. Second, the stuff you are trying to pass as `data` is not at all what you think it is.

`trail.fetch()` doesn't return the the fetch results, it returns the ajax handle for the ajax call that is made with fetch. Thankfully Backbone is made so you don't have to think about all this painful ajax stuff, but instead you can trust the events that Backbone emits. So whip out the [Backbone Catalog o' Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) and check out `reset`

> **"reset"** (collection, options) — when the collection's entire contents have been replaced.

This is the event you collection will emit, after fetch (also `sync`, i think). Before this event is emitted, your collection will be empty, so there is no point in doing anything with it before hearing this `reset` event. So let's bring it all together now:

```
var TrailView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.page',

  template: _.template($("#trailTemplate").html()), // no data attribute here

  initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('reset', this.render);  // render after collection is reset
    this.collection.fetch();  // fetch the collection from the trails.json file
  }

  render: function(){
    // evaluate the template here
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.collection.toJSON())); 
    return this;
  }
});

var trailView = new TrailView({
  collection: trails
});

// trailView.render(); <- No need for this, because it will render itself
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is one of the best responses I have ever received on SO! Thanks!

But, it is still just short of solving the issue, however, I'm sure it must be very close.

When I used exactly what you suggested, I received the following error in the console

"TypeError: this.$el is undefined"

I remember from a CodeSchool tut that sometime you have to set the context when you call render, so I tried modifying the .on event to:
this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);

Now the error I get is:

TypeError: trail is undefined 

_.each(trails,function(trail){

Comment: well, there is no `_.each` -statement in the code you provided so the error is coming from outside the scope of your question

Comment: Hi Jakee,

The _.each statement was in the Underscore template at the very beginning of my question. But I got it figured out!

Just a few changes: this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this); and this.$el.html( this.template( {trails: this.collection.toJSON()} ));

Comment: oh sorry for that, I forgot the template. Great that you figured it out for yourself!